# iterate over a list of list in python

Tags: python, list

I have a list of the following type. I want to normalize this list using the function I have written. for example- normalize (). I want to pass the second innermost list to the normalize(). I want to do it one list at a time.

```
 [[['179.0', '77.0'],
  ['186.0', '93.0'],
  ['175.0', '72.0'],
  ['195.0', '68.0']],
 [['178.0', '76.0'],
  ['185.0', '93.0'],
  ['164.0', '91.0'],
  ['155.0', '117.0']],
  ['161.0', '127.0'],
  ['191.0', '200.0'],
  ['190.0', '241.0'],
  ['194.0', '68.0']],
 [['176.0', '77.0'],
  ['183.0', '93.0'],
  ['163.0', '91.0'],
  ['155.0', '117.0']]......]
```

The code I tried normalizes the whole list. I want to do it row-wise. I have tried following

```
normalized_data = [normalize3(data) for data in load_pose_data()]
```

I would appreciate any help. Thank you

Comment: Next is second innermost? `[['179.0', '77.0'], ['186.0', '93.0'], ['175.0', '72.0'], ['195.0', '68.0']]`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension to achive that.

example:

```
# example function that add element to a list
def f(x):
    return x+[10]

outer_list = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]

# this calls the function on each element
after = [ f(n) for n in outer_list ]

after
[[1, 2, 10], [3, 4, 10], [5, 6, 10]]
```

Comment: if I need one list at a time and keep using f(n) on the subsequent list one by one as mentioned in my post. Do I need to use a loop?

Answer (score 1):

In Addition to @chenshuk's answer, use `lambda`:

```
# example function that add element to a list
f=lambda x: x+[10]
outer_list = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
# this calls the function on each element
after = [ f(n) for n in outer_list ]
```

Use list comprehension.

Or do `map`:

So instead of (list comprehension):

```
after = [ f(n) for n in outer_list ]
```

Do:

```
after = list(map(f,outer_list))
```

Both cases:

```
print(after)
```

Is:

```
[[1, 2, 10], [3, 4, 10], [5, 6, 10]]
```

Comment: I want to give this list by index so that the function will normalize(already written) the data for each index and predict(already written the function logic) for each index.